# Using the split function

Tags: python, if-statement, split

I am trying to split an input to see if the input is in any of the lists I made, however it doesn't output anything. Please help.

```
pyscaldamage =['Casing','casing','Screen','screen','water','wet','Water','Wet','bad','Bad','Speakers','speakers,','Charger','charger','Buttons','buttons']
OSissue = ['crashed','Crashed','Slow','Slow','Freezing','freezing','Rebooting','rebooting','Loading','loading','fails','Fails']
phonesetup = ['Setup','setup','Email','email','WIFI','wifi','Bluetooth','bluetooth','Contacts','contacts','Icloud','icloud']
lol = input('What is the issue? ')
issue = lol.split()
if lol in pyscaldamage:
    fix = open('pyscaldamage.txt','w')
    print('K')
```

Comment: What is your input string to your prompt?

Comment: Have you printed the value of issue, and lol - do they make sense? Also add a print statement inside the if and an else: statement which prints 'lol not found' - now can you understand better what is happening? What is the purpose of the variable issue?

Comment: why do you compute `issue` if you're never going to use it?

Comment: My input would contain words in the pyscaldamage list. A example is 'My phone's casing is damage.'

Comment: I didn't use issue as I was trying to fix it myself. However the issue variable would replace lol in the if statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pyscaldamage =['Casing','casing','Screen','screen','water','wet','Water','Wet','bad','Bad','Speakers','speakers,','Charger','charger','Buttons','buttons']
OSissue = ['crashed','Crashed','Slow','Slow','Freezing','freezing','Rebooting','rebooting','Loading','loading','fails','Fails']
phonesetup = ['Setup','setup','Email','email','WIFI','wifi','Bluetooth','bluetooth','Contacts','contacts','Icloud','icloud']
lol = input('What is the issue? ')
# Examine all the words in the splitted string
# if you lowercase them, the user's case (ScReeN) doesn't matter
# You can also make your searchlist only lowercase with this
if any(issue.lower() in pyscaldamage for issue in lol.split()):
    print('k')
    # This is a better way to open files because you dont have to remember
    # to close them
    with open('pyscaldamage.txt', 'w') as fix:
        # do stuff
        pass # get rid of this once you have stuff in the with statement
```

This approach uses the [any function](http://python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/library/functions.html#any).
The `any` function takes an iterable (think of it like a list for now) and returns `True`
if anything in the iterable is `True`:

```
any([False, True, False]) # returns True
```

Google has good information too. To build that iterable, I'm using something called a `generator expression`.

- It loops through a list: `for issue in lol.split()`
- make a boolean value: `issue.lower() in pyscaldamage`
- moves to the next item

So, a sample generator expression of this form could be something like:

```
my_gen = (x == 2 for x in [1, 2, 3]) # a generator expression
```

Note it's in parentheses. If you open a console it will look somethign like this:

```
In [2]: my_gen = (x == 2 for x in [1,2,3])
Out[2]: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000000009215FC0>
```

You can go through it by calling `next`:

```
In [7]: next(my_gen)
Out[7]: False # x == 1
In [8]: next(my_gen)
Out[8]: True # x == 2
In [8]: next(my_gen)
Out[9]: False # x == 3
```

If you try to keep going, it will yell at you:

```
In[10]: next(my_gen)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-10-3539869a8d50>", line 1, in <module>
    next(my_gen)

StopIteration
```

So, as you can see, you can only use generator expressions once. Generator expressions are iterables,
so `any` can work with them. What this code does is

- creates a list: `lol.split()`
- loops through it: `for issue in lol.split()`
- creates a boolean: `issue.lower() in pyscaldamage`
- asks if anything in this created iterable is True: `any(issue.lower() in pyscaldamage for issue in lol.split())`
- If so, does stuff

Comment: Thanks Ben. The code did work. However I do not understand what is going on. i have to explain this code if I were to use this.

Comment: @Bruhthenewyearjokes - Then choose an approach that you can explain. There are some provided as answers that only minimally differ from yours and might be explainable. This approach is very good (+1) and covers a lot of cases but might a) be overkill for your problem and (b) to hard to explain.

Comment: @MSeifert I have tried all the others and they seem not to work. I have adapted Ben's code however I understand your point.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is that you check if `lol` (that is the inputted string) is in your list. It isn't!

You probably want to check if any of the specific words (these are those you saved in `issue`) is in the list:

```
for string in issue:
    if string in pyscaldamage:
        print('K')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care which token of `lol` is in `pyscaldamage`:

```
issue = lol.split()
if any(token in pyscaldamage for token in issue):
    # do some generic stuff
```

otherwise:

```
issue = lol.split()
for token in issue
    if token in pyscaldamage:
        # do sth. with token
```

Answer (score -1):

Do not use `input`, use `raw_input` instead.

**Note for Python 3.x**

`raw_input` was changed to `input` in Python 3.x as noted in the comments (still available as `eval(input())`).

Comment: This is not true in Python 3.

Comment: It created the file however it does not print k? Could something be conflicting the code?

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is your `if` statement is taking `lol` in considerationinstead of `issue` (that is your `split()` of `lol`). If you try something on the lines of

```
if issue in pyscaldamage:
    fix = open('pyscaldamage.txt','w')
    print('K')
```

It should work.